# DirectX11: Pass data from ComputeShader to VertexShader?

Tags: directx, slimdx, directx-11, vertex-shader, compute-shader

Is it possible to apply a filter to the geometry data that is to be rendered using Compute Shader and then use the result as an input buffer in the Vertex Shader? That would save me the trouble (&time) of reading back the data.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes absolutely. First you create two identicals `ID3D11Buffer` of structures using `BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER`, `BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE`  and `BIND_UNORDERED_ACCESS` usage flags, and the associated UAVs and SRVs.

First step is to apply your filter to input source buffer and write to the destination buffer during your compute pass.

Then during the draw pass, you just have to bind the destination buffer to the `IA` stage. You can do some ping-pong if you need to accumulate computations on the vertices (I assume that by filter you mean a [functional map](http://bit.ly/A3R4R), for refering to the Functional Programming term).